# NPM missing in visual studio 2017

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm

I have Visual Studio 2017 and added support for Node.JS Development and ASP.Net Core. But when I go to Package Manager Console and write

> npm

I am getting following error

> The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

[image]

What could be a problem?

NPM should be fully integrated with VS 
https://webtooling.visualstudio.com/package-managers/npm/

Comment: have you installed [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on the operating system?

Comment: I didnt have installed node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default path for npm is:
C:\%ProgramFiles%\nodejs

You should have a npm.cmd there. The Windows PATH environment variable needs to point to that folder.

My advice is to reinstall nodejs from the source:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

During Setup, making sure you choose Custom Setup and select "Add to PATH" and make sure it is set to "Will be installed on local hard drive".

(Of course, shut down all Visual Studio instances before doing the above.)